# What is on stake for a supervisor in having a PhD student succeed or failing?

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision

I'll turn the question in a different and more precise way:

Can a supervisor profit somehow from the failure of one of his students?

I'll try now to list some possible reasons for supporting this:

- Purely for revenge (must be considered... we are humans after all)
- The student placed the supervisor in some awkward position (by exposing some irregularity, for instance) thus, the supervisor might profit to delegitimize the student in the community.
- The student has adverse opinions toward the subject of the research.

Comment: Since you have answered your own question, what more are you looking for in an answer? Additional motives beyond those you’ve listed? Validation of your theory? Both of those things?

Comment: This is kind of too abstract and general for answers to be very meaningful. Do you want to tell us more details about the specific situation that motivated the question? I suspect you would get higher quality answers.

Comment: First two bullets are the same answer - third bullet suggests the student should not be in the field. Yes please provide more context

Comment: Could you please tell your story so we can judge better?

Comment: Obviously yes, your question provides examples.

Comment: Are you asking whether it might be an advantage for a faculty member to have advised a student that failed? The question is hard to parse.